# How to: quad core and dual quad core virtualization?

Tags: cpu, hyper-v, vmware-server, smp

On top of a dual quad core physical host, I would like to run a single VM with 8 virtual CPU (if possible) or at least 4 virtual CPU - for the purpose of scientific computing.

I have investigated what the market has to offer at this date and it seems that

- VMWare Server 2.0 is limited to 2 virtual CPU.
- Microsoft Virtual Server 2005 RC2 is limited to single CPU.
- Microsoft Hyper-V 2008 is limited to 4 virtual CPU (with restriction on the guest OS).

Is there any solution to get 8 virtual CPUs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Xen, KVM, VirtualBox, all can emulate more CPUs than you have, up to 32 CPUs per VM, at least.

Answer (score 2):

I would investigate VMware's ESXi for your applciation: http://www.vmware.com/products/esxi/.

Their product datasheet: http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/vmware_esxi_datasheet.pdf